# What are the ways in which launch cost/ kg could be reduced below that of the proposed BFR?

Tags: spacex-starship

As seen in this [spacex](https://www.spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/rocket-capability.mp4) video, they claim that the BFR, when ready, would have the lowest marginal cost per launch. Also, it has the maximum payload of the rockets mentioned in the video. Is there any way someone could beat it? If so, by what % of BFR?

Comment: One approach: Find a way to make manufacturing a rocket be so cheap and so cost effective that it would make recycling a rocket be more expensive and more dangerous than it would to build a new one from scratch. A few startups are taking this very path.

Comment: Because there are multiple approaches and because, at least for now, all of those approaches are science fiction (i.e., a Technology Readiness Level of four or less), I'm voting to close as primarily opinion based.

Comment: @DavidHammen: That was basically the philosophy behind the OTRAG launch vehicle.  Though a technological success, its political problems doomed the program.

Comment: The low cost/kg of BFR could be misleading. It's the cost for launching your payload that matters.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to invest money up front, it's pretty much always possible to reduce marginal costs down the road.

Trivially and minimally:

- Step 1: Buy SpaceX.
- Step 2: Remove cameras from the spacecraft and stop doing webcasts of launches.
- Step 3: Remove or drill weight-reducing holes in any features that Elon Musk insisted on for aesthetic reasons

A little more out of the box, and also illegal:

- Step 1: Found a rocket company in a country with significantly lower cost of living than the US
- Step 2: Make it known that you will hire any employee of SpaceX and offer a one-time relocation bonus of 5x their current annual salary, with an additional bonus for any technical information they steal on the way (if everyone took the offer and brought the goods, this would only cost you $7 billion or so)
- Step 3: Develop a BFR clone with the stolen info
- Step 4: Build and fly BFR clones using cheap local labor

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4An1BrG2u_4

Comment: Nice, So good idea to start it in India, China, etc ?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a *good* idea.

Comment: @TejasShetty building a rocket of this complexity requires not only people with a wide variety of skills, but a wide ranged base of vendors and suppliers. You need all kinds of manufacturing technology and equipment and very high quality materials. These obviously exist in India and China based on the success of their space programs, but gaining ready access to them as a new company could be a much bigger challenge there than it would be in the US or Europe (much more so in the case of China, where the lines between companies government and military are pretty blurred).

Comment: @uhoh I can understand China. But why would access be a problem in India?

Comment: @TejasShetty I did add "much more so in the case of China..." but I thought of this again later and I can't support it with citable facts. I'm going to speculate though that the aerospace industry base in the US is much larger and more diverse than the one in India at the moment, and it's likely that the one in India is currently set up to deliver almost exclusively to ISRO, but I could be wrong. I've just left this as a comment rather than an answer, but I think later today I'll ask a new question about this, and I'll ping you here when I do. Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: @uhoh India doesn't seem to have any significant aircraft manufacturing industry. This may be one reason I think it might be tougher for a startup in India. ISRO had to work harder probably to develop those things, which would otherwise be developed by an aircraft device vendor in the US. I don't have any source to back this claim.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, the construction of mega-structures like space elevators, launch loops, or magnetic accelerators would reduce the 'launch' costs as far as possible barring the development of sci-fi tech like warp drives or gravity manipulation systems.

Comment: Why would these necessarily be cheaper?

Comment: @Tejas Shetty as generally described they are powerd by ground based elecricity avoiding the need to lift their propellany and thus the tyrany of the rocket equation.