# What does it take to create a space startup in India?

Tags: isro, career

I wish to create a space startup in my country. Does going to an existing space company(like ISRO) help me as a founder for my startup?

Consider that I have enough investment and I am ready to take risk, I  may choose not to work in a space company. Since Elon Musk didn't go to any space related companies. He had people with industry experience.

If I go to work on a space company now I may get a high level idea on the manufacturing process. After 2 years of experience I will work on other startup ideas to generate income to invest on my company.

Which path shall I choose?

I like to do hands-on leadership.

I am a software developer.
So I can take over the software development part of the company.

Comment: \$$\rm{}\rm{}\rm{}$

Comment: see the comments below [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37326/12102) You'd be better by starting to work for ISRO and learn all you can and gain some reputation and respect within ISRO as a can-do person with good managerial skills. Then if/when you decide to leave and start a company, there is the possibility of doing so "with ISRO's blessings". This industry is growing fast in India but it is not huge yet and you'll need to cooperate rather than compete (at first). You'll also have to shore a wide range of suppliers with them.

Comment: i don't want to compete with isro! i was thinking to co-operate with ISRO's operations  and i guess the budget is the limitation of ISRO. if i have lots of money what can stop us? 
Now gaining that money is a different story

Comment: oops, my re-open vote is accidental, **please ignore**. However, this is quite an interesting read! [The ISRO isn’t enough. India needs its own Elon Musk or Jeff Bezos](https://qz.com/india/1668876/indias-quest-to-take-the-isro-to-the-top/)